# Led button power supply

Tags: led

Can I use a 3V 1A adapter with a push button led which is 3V 20mA. Since the voltage difference is 0 the resistor equations can not be used?

Comment: *Can I ...a push button led which is 3v 20ma* **No, you can't** unless you're happy with destroying that LED. That 3 V 20 mA is only a rough indication, the LED might also pull 100mA or even more and destroy itself. That is why you should **ALWAYS** use a LED with a series resistor. For more details see Andy's answer.

Comment: and: it's actually important to use the proper unit symbols. Volts is "V", not "v", Ampere is "A", not "a", and milliampere is hence "mA", not "ma".

Answer (score 4):

Just because the resistor equation cannot be used, it doesn't make a 3 volt power supply a good match for a 3 volt LED. At 3 volts, the LED may indeed only take (say) 50 mA but at 3.1 volts this current could rise to 500 mA and, in this mind-experiment, might burn the LED beyond repair.

So you choose a random LED from the bag of 3 volt LEDs and it might have a forward volt drop of only 2.9 volts to give 50 mA. You apply 3 volts and smoke.

So say you had an LED that was exactly 3 volts - your power supply might not be very accurate to 3 volts and might generate 3.1 volts and you get more smoke.

LED current does not rise linearly with applied voltage: -

[image]

You might get the above curves for your particular LED or they may even be steeper. Then there are temperature effects on the slope of the graph to consider. Below is the temperature characteristic for an infra red LED: -

[image]

Notice that as the LED gets warmer, the volt drop needed for a particular current reduces. In other words, without a resistor in series with the LED, you could easily get thermal run-away and more smoke.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. What resistor would I need?

Comment: Do you have a link to the data sheet for the led.

Comment: Without details of the LED forward V-I characteristic you cannot calculate a resistor value. Sorry.

Comment: I only have the following information. The button I have is shown in the following link    http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/272085042417?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT      I want to connect it to the mains UK and the adapter I have purchased is show here   http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/262342933804?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT   However I also have the following spare adapters I found at home (1) Output 5.0V 500mA (2) V OUT 3V 580 mA,P OUT I will  1.74VA.....This will be powered on 24 hours & I want to consume the least amount of energy. Thanks

Comment: The switch says that Switch rated value:5A/3V. But I have also been told that it is 3V 20mA.

Comment: Without details of the LED forward V-I characteristic you cannot calculate a resistor value. All the power supply information is irrelevant until the LED characteristic is known.

Comment: OK, I will wait for this to arrive and hope that it contains this detail. Thanks for your assistance Andy.